# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/rt/core/ImportTag

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar, jstl

I'm trying to understand the taglibs from jstl, so i decided to download the sources for it.
My test app was working with the following jars:

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar

Then i changed for:

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1-sources.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-sources.jar

and then i got the error on the title. I don't know why it's not founding the ImportTag. Using archive manager to open the .jar, i can see the ImportTag.java. But when i put the jar on the WEB-INF/lib, and checks the jar through eclipse, all i see is this:

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>agenda</display-name>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/erro.html</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

I'm using tomcat 7 and Java 7.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the sources files in the jars and not the compiled class files. If you include a jar file to the classpath, it should contain the class files not the sources.

Obviously, the source files in the jar won't be compiled.